# Can Alpaca js be used in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frameworks, alpacajs

I have no knowledge in Alpaca Js but when working with forms in React I got a suggestion that Alpaca Forms are efficient for working. So what I want to know is that whether I can integrate Alpaca Js with React js  and also what are difference between them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can integrate AlpacaJs w/ ReactJs using the `componentDidMount` function within an RJS component to initialize alpaca plugin like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.alpacaForm);
  $(el).alpaca(ALPACA_FORM_CONFIG);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/hzcseqbz/) for this.

I have basic knowledge of ReactJs but for what Alpaca can do, it helps you create forms easily by using a simple json schema, I've been using it at work for 3yrs now, it's a good framework, but it has a some limitations (like rendering grouped select box for example, or showing success/error icons...) and the best thing that you can break those limits by creating custom fields and this is the hardest part of alpaca.

Comment: JQuery is a dependency for Alpaca, and JQuery + React have quite a few overlaps in terms of use case. Do consider that if optimising JS file size is a concern.

Comment: Could you please also write how to import alpaca into a React app, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511730/importing-alpaca-into-react-js